# Auto sum total in search filter only - not the whole db

Tags: php, html

```
<table id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: left; width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Total </th>
        <th> Deposit </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
        ?>
            <tr class="record">
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Total </th>
        <th> 
            <?php
                $results = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(contact) FROM student");
                $results->execute();
                for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
                    echo $rows['sum(contact)'];
                }
            ?>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

This is my code. I want to search a certain word only, and that item will generate the sum total, because right now it displays the whole sum of the row in the table. I want the search to generate the sum total can you help me?

Comment: I think you don't have enough empty lines in your code. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting) .

Comment: So you apply a WHERE clause to your database query

Comment: can you give me a example code?

Comment: Describe what your table structure looks like, and what you want to be filtered.

Comment: in a table have deposit and withdraw... in buttom it have total of depo with withdraw.. so when i search.. the filter search only will generate the total.. not the whole in database.. thank so much!

Comment: Are you wanting a `count` of rows that match the word you're looking for, or do you want the query to sum (`+`) two (or more) columns together into a single result column?

Answer (score 0):

While it's unclear what you're asking, here are the two scenarios I can imagine you want:

### A count of rows matching "a certain word only":

```
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(contact) FROM student");
```

First of all, [`sum` is a GROUP BY Aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum). It's unlikely this is what you want in any run-of-the-mill scenario.

Change your query to this:

```
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM student WHERE word = :word");
$results->execute( array( ":word" => "certain" ) );
```

This will count how many rows are returned when you have `certain` in the `word` column.

### A sum of columns

Change your query to something like this:

```
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT ( number1 + number2 ) as totalNumber, * FROM student");
```

This will select every row and add an additional column to the result set called `totalNumber` that holds the sum (`+`) of the columns `number1` and `number2`.

Comment: nothing happens?. can u edit my code.. and put the codes that you given, in me, no happens